# Im getting no postback on my button? I have it tied to Javascript which is tied to a div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Hey guys Im getting no postback on my button? I have it tied to Javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_delete()
{
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?")==true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
</script>
<p>
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="if(confirm_delete()){/* post back*/}else{return false;};" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" runat="server" CssClass="Btn" Text="delete"/>
```

But when I click ok on confirm no postback is initiated, its initiated if I click the button manually?

```
private void PopulateWallPosts(string userId)
{

    using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT idWallPosting, wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN User u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE wp.UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
        {
            //("SELECT wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
            using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                test1.Controls.Clear();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    div.Attributes["class"] = "test";


                    div.ID = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                    // this line is responsible, problem here and my sqlsntax, im trying to set the SELECT idWallPosting for the div ID
                    Image img = new Image();
                    img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));

                    img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                    div.Controls.Add(img);
                    div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;" + "{0}", reader.GetString(1))));
                    div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete();");

                    div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                    test1.Controls.Add(div);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_26";
    string[] idFragments = id.Split('_');
    id = idFragments[idFragments.Length - 1];

    //serverside code if confirm was pressed.
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM WallPosting WHERE idWallPosting = " + id + ")", cn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        //PopulateWallPosts();

}
```

**EDIT:** Tried this:

```
function confirm_delete()
{
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?") == true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
</script>
<p>
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="return confirm_delete();" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" runat="server" CssClass="Btn" Text="delete"/>
```

still no postback

Comment: In my original code I think im missing __dopostback() not sure how its done by the answers below are wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that you're explicitly telling asp.net that your confirmation was successful.  Remember if you don't return something, then it will default to false.  Your `OnClientClick` should just be `"return confirm_delete();"`, then it should work.

`OnClientClick` is always suppposed to return a boolean letting ASP.NET know that it should indeed post back and fire your server-side `OnClick` event.

Comment: tryed that, its tied to a div i will post more code but it still isnt posting back

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
runat="server"
```

in the button tag